# make layout-items allgn in same level in form LWC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

I have this below code where i am trying to allign output fields and edit icon in the same line. But it is coming as below picture - 
How to make both the fields bottom border in align.

[image]

```
<lightning-layout-item padding="horizontal-small" size="6">
                    <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters slds-border_bottom">
                        <div class="slds-col">
                            <span>
                                <lightning-output-field field-name="Amount"
                                    style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
                                </lightning-output-field>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-col">
                          <span>
                            <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:edit" icon-class="slds-button__icon_hint" variant="bare"
                            alternative-text="Edit Record" onclick={editRecord}></lightning-button-icon>
                          </span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                </lightning-layout-item>
                <lightning-layout-item padding="horizontal-small" size="6">
                    <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters slds-border_bottom">
                        <div class="slds-col">
                            <span>
                                <lightning-output-field field-name="Test_Checking_Test_Receipt_Date__c"
                                    style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
                                </lightning-output-field>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-col">
                          <span>
                            <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:edit" icon-class="slds-button__icon_hint" variant="bare"
                            alternative-text="Edit Record" onclick={editRecord}></lightning-button-icon>
                          </span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                </lightning-layout-item>
```

Comment: Instead of lightning-layout you could just try wrapping them in a flex-box and have them align to flex-end. Should align items on the bottom of their container.

Comment: so for lightning-layout.. it won't work?

Comment: Probably, you'd just need to CSS some stuff to make it work. It just seems simpler to me to use a flex box to achieve this.

Comment: so  you want "Test_Checking_Test_Receipt_Date__c" field to come in one line?

Comment: yes correct..Amount and Test_Checking_Test_Receipt_Date__c field to be in line